# Angular-CLI 'ng build --prod' fails ERROR in Error: Can't resolve all parameters for RoutesListingService

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an @angular-cli app that I can execute the 'ng build' successfully, however when I attempt 'ng build --prod' it fails to create the distribution. I get this error:

```
ERROR in Error: Can't resolve all parameters for RoutesListingService in C:dev/src/app/core/routes.service.ts: (?).
    at syntaxError (C:dev\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
```

Does anyone know why this is happeneing or have any suggestions as to how to fix this?

The RouteListing Service is being used to help compile a collection of the app routes to be used for a sibebar navigation menu.
The software versions I am using are as follows:

```
@angular/cli: 1.4.9
node: 8.7.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.6
@angular/common: 4.4.6
@angular/compiler: 4.4.6
@angular/core: 4.4.6
@angular/forms: 4.4.6
@angular/http: 4.4.6
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.6
@angular/router: 4.4.6
@angular/cli: 1.4.9
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.6
@angular/language-service: 4.4.6
typescript: 2.5.3
```

**File: angular-cli.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "dev"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "deployUrl": "https://10.10.10.10/dev/app/",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "./assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "class": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "component": {
    }
  },
  "warnings": {
    "typescriptMismatch": false
  }
}
```

The admin component is used to get the route and metadata (data) from the routing-modules.

**File: admin.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-admin',
    templateUrl: 'admin.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['admin.component.css']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {
    public routes: Routes;
    userRole: string;  
    constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.routes = this.router.config, 'data';   
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.userRole = localStorage.getItem('auth_role');
     }
}
```

**File: admin.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let route of routes | filter:userRole" class="slds-p-right--medium slds-size--3-of-3">
    <a [routerLink]=" '/' + route.path" class="slds-app-launcher__tile slds-text-link--reset">
        <div class="slds-app-launcher__tile-figure">
            <span class="slds-avatar slds-avatar--medium slds-align--absolute-center"><img class="logo" [src]="route.data.icon"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-app-launcher__tile-body" *ngIf="route.data">
            <span class="slds-text-title"><strong>{{route.data.title}}</strong></span>
            <p class="slds-text-body--small">{{route.data.description}}
            </p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

The filter pipe is used to collect all the metadata for all the components and build the menu collection based on the components that have metadata and based on the role permission the user has when logged in.

**File: filter.pipe.ts**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';    
import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
})    
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    toBeSortedRouteList: any[];
    transform(routes: Routes, allowed_role: string): any {
        this.toBeSortedRouteList = _.chain(routes)
            .filter('data')
            .filter(function(route) {
                return (_.indexOf(route.data.role, allowed_role) !== -1) ;
            })
            .value();    
        this.toBeSortedRouteList = _.sortBy(this.toBeSortedRouteList, 'data.rank')    
        return this.toBeSortedRouteList;
    }
}
```

**File: routes.service.ts**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

    @Injectable()
    export class RoutesListingService {
        public appRoutes: Routes[];

        constructor(private routes: Routes[]) {
            this.appRoutes = routes;
        }

}
```

The below is an example of a component routing-module. In this case one for showing a list of SSL Certificates.

**File: sslcert-routing-module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { SslCertComponent } from './sslcert.component';
import { AddSslCertFormComponent } from './addsslcert-form.component';
import { EditSslCertFormComponent } from './editsslcert-form.component';

import { AuthGuard } from '../core/auth-guard.service';
import { RoutesListingService } from '../core/routes.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'certificates',
    component: SslCertComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: {
      title: 'SSL Certs',
      description: 'Manage UCC lab SSL Certificates.',
      icon: './assets/images/safe-icon48.png',
      rank: 3,
      role: ['ROLE_GUEST', 'ROLE_OPERATOR', 'ROLE_ADMIN']
    },
  },
  { path: 'certificates/addsslcert', component: AddSslCertFormComponent },
  { path: 'certificates/editsslcert/:id', component: EditSslCertFormComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [AuthGuard, RoutesListingService]
})
export class SslCertRoutingModule { }

export const routedComponents = [SslCertComponent, AddSslCertFormComponent, EditSslCertFormComponent];
```

Comment: You're trying to inject an array of Routes (i.e. an array of arrays of Route) in your service. There is no service with that type. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The app works as is. I can perform an 'ng build' which creates all the main, vendor, etc. bundles and I can deploy the app to my Tomcat server. I can launch the app, login, display data and everything else the app is supposed to do. I want to minimize the bundle sizes and create a production version of the app, but the 'ng build --prod' process fails. If I need to use InjectionToken I will, but I didn't need it for the 'ng build' so that is the confusing part.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to inject routes, then you should provide it with `InjectionToken`:

```
const RoutesToken:InjectionToken<Routes> = new InjectionToken<Routes>('routes');


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [AuthGuard, RoutesListingService, {provide: RoutesToken, useValue: routes}]
})


@Injectable()
export class RoutesListingService {
    public appRoutes: Routes;

    constructor(private @Inject(RoutesToken) routes: Routes) {
        this.appRoutes = routes;
    }

}
```

Comment: I can see how to add the RoutesToken to each component's routing-module, but how do I import it into the shared RoutesListingService?

Comment: using regular import: `import {RoutesToken} from '...'`

Comment: I have 18 components. Wouldn't I need an array of RoutesToken for all of them? Also, the Webstorm or VS Code IDE says I have an error in the

Comment: Accidentally hit Enter before finishing my comment. The fix for the error was to remove 'private' in the constructor     constructor(@Inject(RoutesToken) routes: Routes) {
        this.appRoutes = routes;
    }